# How can I know which instance of BizTalk has been used by a message?

Tags: instance, biztalk

We have an environment for three instances of BizTalk 2016 that are used randomly by the messages. 
I would need to know which one has been used when I send a message, but only if it has had any error and it is shown in the `Windows logs-->Application` is said which computer was used.
But I'd need to know which computer was used when the message was fine, but in the 'Tracked Message Events' this information is not shown and the flow of the message is displayed in the three instances.
Any idea of how I could get this information?

Comment: It would help to know why you need this and what exactly will be done with this data.  There are multiple options.

Answer (score 0):

The fact of the matter is that it could be anyone of the three servers within your BizTalk Group. What you could do is track the properties and in the send pipeline promote the machine name. Although I'm not sure why you would need to do this.

Please remember that a send port can be triggered by any server with a particular host instance configured and running and that retry attempts may even be done on other server(s) as long as the triggered host instance is running there.